# Same amount charged with multiple stripe checkout forms

Tags: javascript, php, forms, checkout

I have 3 checkout forms on a webpage to let a user choose between 3 plans (9,99 - 29,99 - 49,99). Each of them are processed by a different php script but regardless which plan the user is choosing, the last plan is always being processed (49,99).
So I'm looking for a solution to solve this problem.

Thanks

```
<div class="row m-t-30">

    <!--Pricing Column-->
    <article class="pricing-column col-md-4">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <div class="plan-header text-center">
                <h3 class="plan-title">Up to 10 members</h3>
                <h2 class="plan-price">9.99€</h2>
                <div class="plan-duration">Per Month</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <form id="formplan1" action="scripts/process-payment-plan1.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken1" name="stripeToken1" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail1" name="stripeEmail1" />
                    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
                    <button id="pay1" class="btn btn-custom btn-bordred waves-effect waves-light">Choose Plan</button>
                    <script>
                        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                            key: 'pk_test_fC2yWHeQJA93fFr0MlnKrAW4',
                            image: '../assets/img/logos/Logo_1_01.png',
                            locale: 'auto',
                            token: function(token) {
                                $("#stripeToken1").val(token.id);
                                $("#stripeEmail1").val(token.email);
                                $("#formplan1").submit();
                                // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
                                // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
                            }
                        });

                        document.getElementById('pay1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                            // Open Checkout with further options:
                            handler.open({
                                name: 'Subscription',
                                description: 'Up to 10 members',
                                zipCode: false,
                                amount: 999,
                                currency: 'EUR',
                                allowrememberme: true,
                                email: '<?php echo $userinfo['
                                UserEmail '] ;?>',
                            });
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        // Close Checkout on page navigation:
                        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
                            handler.close();
                        });
                    </script>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>

    <!--Pricing Column-->
    <article class="pricing-column col-md-4">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <div class="plan-header text-center">
                <h3 class="plan-title">From 11 to 40 members</h3>
                <h2 class="plan-price">29.99€</h2>
                <div class="plan-duration">Per Month</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <form id="formplan2" action="scripts/process-payment-plan2.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken2" name="stripeToken2" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail2" name="stripeEmail2" />
                    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
                    <button id="pay2" class="btn btn-custom btn-bordred waves-effect waves-light">Choose Plan</button>
                    <script>
                        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                            key: 'pk_test_fC2yWHeQJA93fFr0MlnKrAW4',
                            image: '../assets/img/logos/Logo_1_01.png',
                            locale: 'auto',
                            token: function(token) {
                                $("#stripeToken2").val(token.id);
                                $("#stripeEmail2").val(token.email);
                                $("#formplan2").submit();
                                // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
                                // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
                            }
                        });

                        document.getElementById('pay2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                            // Open Checkout with further options:
                            handler.open({
                                name: 'Subscription',
                                description: 'From 11 to 40 members',
                                zipCode: false,
                                amount: 2999,
                                currency: 'EUR',
                                allowrememberme: true,
                                email: '<?php echo $userinfo['
                                UserEmail '] ;?>',
                            });
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        // Close Checkout on page navigation:
                        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
                            handler.close();
                        });
                    </script>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>

    <!--Pricing Column-->
    <article class="pricing-column col-md-4">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <div class="plan-header text-center">
                <h3 class="plan-title">From 41 to 100 members</h3>
                <h2 class="plan-price">49.99€</h2>
                <div class="plan-duration">Per Month</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <form id="formplan3" action="scripts/process-payment-plan3.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken3" name="stripeToken3" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail3" name="stripeEmail3" />
                    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
                    <button id="pay3" class="btn btn-custom btn-bordred waves-effect waves-light">Choose Plan</button>
                    <script>
                        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                            key: 'pk_test_fC2yWHeQJA93fFr0MlnKrAW4',
                            image: '../assets/img/logos/Logo_1_01.png',
                            locale: 'auto',
                            token: function(token) {
                                $("#stripeToken3").val(token.id);
                                $("#stripeEmail3").val(token.email);
                                $("#formplan3").submit();
                                // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
                                // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
                            }
                        });

                        document.getElementById('pay3').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                            // Open Checkout with further options:
                            handler.open({
                                name: 'Subscription',
                                description: 'From 41 to 100 members',
                                zipCode: false,
                                amount: 4999,
                                currency: 'EUR',
                                allowrememberme: true,
                                email: '<?php echo $userinfo['
                                UserEmail '] ;?>',
                            });
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        // Close Checkout on page navigation:
                        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
                            handler.close();
                        });
                    </script>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>

</div>
```

> Providing Form handling through PHP

**For form 1**

```
   <?php // Create a customer using a Stripe token
    require('../../stripe/init.php');
    // Be sure to replace this with your actual test API key
    // (switch to the live key later)
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_SAOfTRF7qSqgJIfa9sWN33cw");

    try
    {
      $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail1'],
        'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken1'],
        'plan' => '1'
      ));

      echo "payment processed";
      //exit;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
      echo "problem during payment processing<br>";
      echo $e->getMessage();
      //header('Location:oops.html');
      error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
        ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

**For Form 2**

```
    <?php // Create a customer using a Stripe token
require('../../stripe/init.php');


// Be sure to replace this with your actual test API key
// (switch to the live key later)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_SAOfTRF7qSqgJIfa9sWN33cw");

try
{
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail2'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken2'],
    'plan' => 'plan2'
  ));

  echo "payment processed";
  //exit;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo "problem during payment processing<br>";
  echo $e->getMessage();
  //header('Location:oops.html');
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

**For Form 3**

```
    <?php // Create a customer using a Stripe token
require('../../stripe/init.php');


// Be sure to replace this with your actual test API key
// (switch to the live key later)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_SAOfTRF7qSqgJIfa9sWN33cw");

try
{
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail3'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken3'],
    'plan' => 'plan3'
  ));

  echo "payment processed";
  //exit;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo "problem during payment processing<br>";
  echo $e->getMessage();
  //header('Location:oops.html');
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have ants on your TAB ?

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: _“Each of them are processed by a different php script”_ - that sounds rather nonsense-y already. And without evidence to the contrary, I would also doubt if their `checkout.js` script is even supposed to be embedded into a document multiple times. I think you should rather use one single form for this, and in that offer the user the choice between your plans via radio buttons or sth. like that. And then based on what the user selects, you dynamically fill in the right values for the API call parameters.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the facti is that I didn't want to use radio buttons. do you think there is anotherway ?